# WSO2 MDM solution installation

Tags: wso2

Does WSO2's MDM solution install on a Windows server because all of it's installation files are Linux. Do I have to use Linux? if s,o which box should I use?

Comment: See if this link helps: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Installing+on+Windows

Comment: Yes it does. Check the link shared by isim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install JAVA and configure JAVA_HOME Environment variable. You can use below link for details

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Installing+on+Windows

then On Windows, choose Start -> Run, type cmd at the prompt, and press Enter. locate EMM_HOME folder\bin and type wso2server.bat --run

```
 <EMM_HOME>\bin\wso2server.bat --run
```

All necessary details are clearly mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Running+the+Product guide